# How to return value when 2 for loops are completed?

Tags: typescript, angular8

My code makes for-loop queries in the database and does computation in the front-end.

How do I display values only when computation is completed and all for loops are done?

This is my process:

```
startQuery() {
    this.loading = true;

    const queryInfo = {
      //from form field
    }

    this.report = {};

    //first DB query
    this.angularService.getTime(queryInfo).subscribe(data => {

      const first = data.accounts;

      for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {

        this.report[first[i].firstName] = {
          firstName: first[i].firstName,
        };

        const totalDays = 30;
        for (let dayNum = 0; dayNum <= totalDays; dayNum++) {

          const employeeId = first[i].eeid;

          //Second query from DB
          this.angularService.getTimeRecord(employeeId, ).subscribe(data => {

            //process data 

          })
        }
      }

      this.resultDetails = []

      for (var subObj in this.report) {
        this.resultDetails.push(this.report[subObj]);
      }
    })

    this.loading = false;
}
```

In my html, the spinner is supposed to be displayed if this.loading = true, and display values only if this.loading is false. The result is that
Spinner displays momentarily and values are displayed, however, displayed is usually not complete. I have to click the startQuery button 2 or 3 times before the values displayed are complete.

How do I make sure that all DB queries and frontend computation is complete before values are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startQuery() {
    this.loading = true;

    const queryInfo = {
      //from form field
    }

    this.report = {};

    //first DB query
    this.angularService.getTime(queryInfo).subscribe(data => {

      const first = data.accounts;

      for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {

        this.report[first[i].firstName] = {
          firstName: first[i].firstName,
        };

        const totalDays = 30;
        let responseCount = 0;
        for (let dayNum = 0; dayNum <= totalDays; dayNum++) {

          const employeeId = first[i].eeid;

          //Second query from DB
          this.angularService.getTimeRecord(employeeId, ).subscribe(data => {
              responseCount ++;
              if (responseCount == totalDays){
                   this.loading = false;
               }
            //process data 

          })
        }
      }

      this.resultDetails = []

      for (var subObj in this.report) {
        this.resultDetails.push(this.report[subObj]);
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: The loop did not include the first loop where first.length